# .c extension vs .C extension

Tags: c, pointers, warnings, codeblocks, deprecation-warning

I was trying to compile a very simple program, which stores the base address of a string literal in a *pointer to char* `p` and then printing the string using pointer `p` as the following:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char *p = "hello";
    printf("%s", p);
    return 0;
}
```

By mistake, I saved the file with `.C` extension instead of `.c` extension and I saw that when I compile using `.C` extension there was an additional warning:

```
deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’
```

which was not there when I compiled the program with `.c` extension, I am using *Code::Blocks 16.01*. What is actually happening here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, your compiler conventionally treats .C files as C++ sources, where this conversion is truly deprecated. If you rename it to .cpp then the compiler output should probably stay the same.

Comment: so is there any rule in standard  for this or is it just compiler to compiler dependent ? and also will it have same effect on all the programs that i compile using .C instead of .c ?

Comment: I don't believe any of the working standards specifies requirements on source file naming (there can be no source file after all.) This is merely a popular convention.

Comment: @Noshiii This might also depend on your OS. Linux is case-sensitive, Windows is not. As for the C standard, it makes no requirements at all regarding how to name source files.